# IOException and FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, ioexception, filenotfoundexception, fileoutputstream

Have some errors in this code:

> Error(18,40):  unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
>   Error(19,42):  unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

But when FileNotFound and IOException exceptions are thrown, compiler shows this error:

> Error(15,27):  removeEldestEntry(java.util.Map.Entry) in  cannot override removeEldestEntry(java.util.Map.Entry) in java.util.LinkedHashMap; overridden method does not throw java.io.IOException

Whats the problem?
Code is here:

```
package client;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;


public class level1 {


private static final int max_cache = 50;

private Map cache = new LinkedHashMap(max_cache, .75F, true) {
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest)  {
        boolean removed = super.removeEldestEntry(eldest);
        if (removed) {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("t.tmp");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

            oos.writeObject(eldest.getValue());

            oos.close();
        }
        return removed;
    }

};


public level1() {
    for (int i = 1; i < 52; i++) {
        String string = String.valueOf(i);
        cache.put(string, string);
        System.out.println("\rCache size = " + cache.size() +
                           "\tRecent value = " + i + " \tLast value = " +
                           cache.get(string) + "\tValues in cache=" +
                           cache.values());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this..

```
package client;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Level1 {

    private static final int max_cache = 50;
    private Map cache = new LinkedHashMap(max_cache, .75F, true) {

        @Override
        protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {
            boolean removed = super.removeEldestEntry(eldest);
            if (removed) {
                FileOutputStream fos;
                try {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream("t.tmp");

                    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

                    oos.writeObject(eldest.getValue());

                    oos.close();

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.err.println("IOException!!");
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    System.err.println("FileNotFoundException!!");
                }
            }
            return removed;
        }
    };

    public level1() {
        for (int i = 1; i < 52; i++) {
            String string = String.valueOf(i);
            cache.put(string, string);
            System.out.println("\rCache size = " + cache.size()
                    + "\tRecent value = " + i + " \tLast value = "
                    + cache.get(string) + "\tValues in cache="
                    + cache.values());

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the FileNotFoundException inside your removeEldestEntry method (handle as in, catch it and log it). You're not allowed to tack new exceptions onto the method signature when you override a method, because then your subclass is no longer substitutable for the thing you're subclassing.

Otherwise find a different way to do it so that your removeEldestEntry queues the entries up and something else reads the queue and does the serializing to a file. Actually after reading the Javadoc it seems like there must be a better place to put this logic, the same code that actually performs the removal would probably be a better place to do the serializing.